# What are the research topics of Latin scholars?

Tags: academic-latin

Given that dozens of grammars and dictionaries exist I wonder what questions the Latin scholars are working on.

Are there any big unknowns left?

The only one I can think of is the author of classic works like *De Bello Africo*.

Comment: Good question! While the answers will be obvious (and even too many to list) to those working in the field, it's hard to tell from the outside. This kind of description of a field is hard to find.

Comment: There's the *Thesaurus linguae Latinae* (https://thesaurus.badw.de/en/project.html), a monolingual Latin dictionary covering all surviving Latin text up to 600 AD. Last time I checked, they were up to *R*.